# XSD regex for "four alphanumerics, but not all digits"?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, logic, alphanumeric

I'm trying to write an XML Schema datatype for an element that must contain four alphanumerics (uppercase only), but not the all-digit combinations.

Stated in other words, a sequence of four of A-Z or 0-9, containing at least one of A-Z.

It's the latter part I'm having difficulty with, the "at least one" or "but not".

I've thought of and/or tried:

*character class subtraction (but I think that there's no way to define the "classes" here?)*

```
<!-- no example -->
```

*combining 2 xs:restrictions*

```
<xs:restriction>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-Z]{4}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:pattern value="[^(\d\d\d\d)]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
```

*combining 2 xs:patterns in two datatypes*

```
  <xs:simpleType name="4alpha-at-least-one-letter">
    <xs:restriction base="my-namespace:FourAlphanumericsType">
      <xs:pattern value="[^(\d\d\d\d)]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="FourAlphanumericsType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-Z]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I guess these are all dead ends, and I'm either missing something in the regular expression world, or XML regex is maybe not the best way to do this?

Comment: You will have to spell out the regex: [`"[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3}|[A-Z0-9][A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}|[A-Z0-9]{2}[A-Z][A-Z0-9]|[A-Z0-9]{3}[A-Z]"`](https://regex101.com/r/0ANOYi/1) because you cannot use lookaheads here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the length is fixed, another simple solution is to combine *xs:pattern* and  *xs:length* restrictions:

```
<xs:simpleType name="x">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*"/>
     <xs:length value="4"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Love it!  This is worthy of being the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

XML Schema regex does not support lookarounds, so you can only spell out the regex:

```
<xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3}|[A-Z0-9][A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}|[A-Z0-9]{2}[A-Z][A-Z0-9]|[A-Z0-9]{3}[A-Z]"/>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ANOYi/1).

If you need to also match lowercase letters, add `a-z` into ech `[...]` (character class).

Comment: There are way more possible combinations, though. I think it's something like 2 * 4! isn't it?

Comment: You need to make sure there is at least 1 alpha char within a 4 char alphanumeric string, right? So, the expression above should work. Please try it online and let me know what you expect in real life.

Comment: Now I look at it again I see how it works; each of the 4 positions is limited to only alpha, in turn. Yup, that's logically consistent with "at least one alpha. **NICE** thinking!

Answer (score 3):

***Update***: Don't miss [sergioFC's clever approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317857/290085).  I'll leave my answer up here for any useful tidbits it might have, but sergioFC's is the best solution overall.

---

### XSD 1.0

A slight readability improvement can be attained over Wiktor Stribiżew's [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40301334/290085) (+1) by using multiple patterns:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AtLeastOneLetterInFourAlphaType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3}"/>
     <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9][A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}"/>
     <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9]{2}[A-Z][A-Z0-9]"/>
     <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9]{3}[A-Z]"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

(In XSD, multiple patterns represent alternation.)

### XSD 1.1

XSD 1.1's assertion facility can express the constraint that the value must not be numeric, which effectively requires at least one of the characters expressed in the partner pattern to be non-numeric:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AtLeastOneLetterInFourAlphaType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9]{4}"/>
    <xs:assertion test="not($value castable as xs:integer)"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Do you mean (In XSD, multiple patterns represent **alternatives**.)

Comment: See second sense of [***alternation***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alternation).

Comment: Thanks @kjhuges - inclusive disjunction for the win!